Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job, The type interface does not contain a method with signature
I am working on .NET Core 8 and HangFire 1.8.12 solution to run few recurring jobs. I have below code for interface
public interface IDatabaseMgtJobs
{
    Task<int> BackupMyDatabase();
}

I have implemented this interface and added required DI code to startup class.
I need to schedule this method to run on daily basis and I have added below code to setup recurring job using Hangfire jobs
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IDatabaseMgtJobs>("backupMainDB", (Expression<Action<IDatabaseMgtJobs>>)(mgt => mgt.BackupMyDatabase()), cronexp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"), "database");

With this code, I am able to place a job to Hangfire server but when its time to run the job its failing with below exception.

Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
System.InvalidOperationException: The type MIS.Interface.Database.IDatabaseMgtJobs does not contain a method with signature BackupMyDatabase()
at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob() in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Storage\InvocationData.cs:line 109
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob() in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Storage\InvocationData.cs:line 120
at Hangfire.RecurringJobExtensions.TriggerRecurringJob(IBackgroundJobFactory factory, JobStorage storage, IStorageConnection connection, IProfiler profiler, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\RecurringJobExtensions.cs:line 115
at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now) in C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Server\RecurringJobScheduler.cs:line 333

I am bit familiar with HangFire Jobs, but not sure this time what is wrong with this code. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance !

Why do you cast the job call expression to Expression<Action<IDatabaseMgtJobs>>?

@Prolog earlier I got an error "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type."
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobEnum.ToString(), mgt => mgt.BackupMyDatabase(), cronexp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"), HangFireQueues.database.ToString());
I fixed by casting and able to create a recurring job but failing when triggered

The above code works perfectly fine, I was passing Enum value to job titile which is causing an unexpected behavior. Thanks.

mark as answered
